# CentOS 7 Minimal Install doesn't comes with networks scripts? Which version to use then?

Tags: centos, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, centos7

I'm installing CentOS 7 as virtual machine but I'm having some problems related to network. As image shows I select `Minimal Install` for later add trough YUM any packages I want as for example: PHP, Nginx, MySQL and so on since this will be a web development enviroment. After the installation, and having the network configured on Vmware Workstation as second image shows, when I logging I can't start network also I can't access to `setup` or something else, so, what I'm missing? Which version of all is the right to install? And of course the most clean installation without extras

[image]
[image]

**Figured out how to get network up, now can't install any groups**

Finally and after take a closer look at `/etc/sysconfig/networks-scripts` I found that my network isn't called `eth0` as always instead CentOS generate a ugly name, in this case how I can change that name for `eth0`?

Now as second point I tried this commands:

```
yum groupinstall "System Management"
yum groupinstall "System Administration Tools"
```

And in both cases I get this message:

> Warning: Group system-management/system-administration-tools does not
>   have any packages to install Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see
>   man yum) No packages in any requested group available for install or
>   update

And I get lost since I'm trying to install tools like `setup` and so others, what I miss on this? Is the command right? Do I need to enable something in somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access to setup or something else"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde I mean when I type `setup` on console OS said program not found also if I try something like `ifup eth0` I get no script configuration for network so I think I miss something during installation or minimal is just minimal and I need to add a lot of things, in that case to get the most complete but also clean installation what option I should pick?

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde since this will be a development server I wouldn't need any GUI since I like command line and by clean I mean just the necessary for connect trough network from host (Windows in my case) and them start configuring all that I need like Web Development tools

Comment: Can you paste `ifconfig -a` and availability of networking scripts in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` ?

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde `ifconfig -a command not found`

Comment: Try `/sbin/ifconfig -a`, just to be sure.  But you may be right, they may have finally retired the `ifconfig` command in favour of the more monolithic `ip` (grumble).

Comment: @MadHatter I think it's not present due to "Minimal" setup, I've tried to install groups and I can't maybe you can take a look to my edition in order to see if I'm doing things in the right way

Comment: The `ifconfig` command is part of the `net-tools` package, which isn't part of the minimal install; whereas the `ip` tool is part of `iproute`, which is.  You can get `ifconfig` back by installing `net-tools`.

Comment: I agree that the group handling seems somewhat broken at the moment.

Comment: @MadHatter for convert "Minimal" to "Basic" what will you install?

Comment: I'm not planning on running a second install just to answer that; you try it!  I've told you how to get `ifconfig`, which is what I wanted to know.

Comment: @MadHatter I think you miss understand me, I'm not asking you to did a second install just asking for common packages you could install on Minimal to get Basic

Comment: Without installing Basic, I don't know either.  Sorry.

Comment: This question is all over the place. You need to ask a single question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

> nmcli & nmtui

If you are using "minimal installation" then all other rpm for web development you need to install separately.

For status of your nic /ip as follow

> ip a sh

This is how all servers should be setup. Absolutely bare bones and then add only the services/applications that define its role.

Comment: Can you take a look to my latest edition? I figured out the network part but I'm still having problems with others